# Setting image for tableviewcell slows scrolling in Swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, tableview

I wand to load the image from a url and set it for the table view cell.
If I do it without async it slows the table view. Otherwise, if I set within async block some images are shown incorrectly and the will be changed asynchronous.

in second approach - async 
table view cells are reused, and it takes some times to get the image and change it. so for a short time, tableview cell shows the previous image and it is incorrect.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                var userPhoto: UIImage?

                if let imageUrl = participant?.image {
                    let url = URL(string:imageUrl)
                    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
                    {
                        userPhoto = UIImage(data: data)
                    }
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let userPhoto = userPhoto {
                        self.imageViewOwner.image = userPhoto
                    } else {
                        // Sets default image for profile.
                        self.imageViewOwner.image = UIImage(named: "default")
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem is exactly? You shouldn't do networking / loading data synchronously, so your approach is correct. What do you mean with 'images are shown incorrectly'?

Comment: @Marcel Thanks. I added some details to my post. table view cells are reused, and it takes some times to get the image and change it. so for a short time, tableview cell shows the previous image and it is incorrect.

Comment: You can use kingfisher, sd web image or alamofire image .
These are some really decent libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it the "async" way is the right way.

I'd advice to create a separate class to use the DownloadingService for initiating image requests, keeping track of which image is already downloaded and which one is not.

Make your View Controller (or whatever object is your Table View Data Source) use the object above to get the image object (from memory or from Disk Cache; you should probably cache images once downloaded). If that object is not available - just use some default image everywhere (it can be a Loading Indicator image, a User Avatar image etc.).

Perhaps you'll have to create a custom cell and override `prepareForReuse()` method. Set the Default image for the cell there, and that will not display old / incorrect images on cells, in case the current download is still in progress while cell is being displayed.

Note: Whether you use an open-source library or not, the steps are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

```
self.imageViewOwne.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "default"))
```